# Limitations of application dictionary in openbravo

Tags: openbravo

I am using openbravo3.0 since 5 months, and i am wondering what are the limitations of application dictionary in openbravo(what are the things that are not possible in application dictionary?). I searched in internet but could not get any result related to it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One of the limitation of application dictionary is,
You cannot develop a page with radio buttons,Obviously you can add it to the manual window. To achieve this functionality in standard application window you need to use checkbox and write validation for the checkbox fields so that if one is checked the other should be disabled. Check out this link
 https://issues.openbravo.com/view.php?id=6459

Comment: Also you cannot develop a standard window by combining two tables. You have to use single table itself for single window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you CAN develop pages with Radio Buttons in Openbravo 3 using custom References. And you can develop any new type of input entry or data display using those.
You can also embed custom widgets into any part of an Application Dictionary screen.

The limitation comes more in a form of layout (lines & max 4 columns) even though this could be overcome in some cases again using custom references.

The question really is how far you should be bending the standard window (with grid/ form editing) with custom development as opposed to developing an entire custom window from scratch based on your UI needs.

Openbravo 3's flexibility has really come a long way and many limitations that were present before have been much improved.
Someone with a strong Java & Javascript background can customize and extend Openbravo in depth. What is even more important, you can do that in a modular way, not having to customize the core and leaving your upgrade path open and cleaner.